# How can I simplify C# code that sets multiple properties of an object?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I have code that looks like this:

```
itemView.Question.AnswersJSON = itemView.Answer.ToJSONString();
itemView.Question.Modified = DateTime.Now;
itemView.Question.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name
```

plus many more lines where I set values for the `Question` class that is inside the `itemView`.

I think the answer is "not possible" but just putting it out as a question in case anyone knows a way.

What I would like to do is to find a way to simplify this code without repeating `itemView.Question` in every line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `Question` is a `class` (not a `struct`), then you could assign it to a local variable, and edit that:

```
Question q = itemView.Question;
q.AnswersJSON = itemView.Answer.ToJSONString();
q.Modified = DateTime.Now;
q.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name
```

You won't even have to assign `q` back to `itemView.Question`.

This is because classes in C# are [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).  If you assign an instance of a reference type to a local variable, or pass it to a function, then changes to that instance will be reflected everywhere you have a reference to that same instance.

**Edit**

Note that the situation might be a bit murky if `Question` is a property of `itemView`, rather than a field.  Depending on how it is implemented, you might have to assign `q` back to `Question`.  In such a case, this code is still much preferred to avoid calling the `Question` property's getter method repeatedly.

Comment: The class/struct distinction is important here, +1 for explaining it and reference types. That makes this answer better than the other similar ones.

Comment: since this is all about less typing then use var q = itemView.Question this saves 5 chars

Answer (score 27):

Do you instantiate itemView.Question as part of your method?

If so you could do:-

```
itemView.Question = new ItemViewQuestion()
{
  AnswersJSON = itemView.Answer.ToJSONString(),
  Modified = DateTime.Now,
  ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name
};
```

Answer (score 17):

One option is that you can convert your properties into methods that return 'this'.

Then you could write:

```
itemView.Question
    .AnswersJSON(itemView.Answer.ToJSONString())
    .Modified(DateTime.Now)
    .ModifiedBy(User.Identity.Name);
```

I've heard this style called 'fluent interface', and find it pretty handy. I sometimes create properties and a matching set methods returning 'this' called SetXXXX to compliment them.

The popular Rhino Mocks framework for unit testing uses it. More examples here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99542/Guidelines-to-Fluent-Interface-design-in-C-Part-1

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how much control you have over the `Question` class, separating the resposibility for setting that meta-data may be an idea:

```
class Question {
    ...
    public void SetAnswer(Answer answer) {
        this.AnswersJSON = answer.ToJSONString();
        this.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        this.Modified = User.Identity.Name; // or pass the user into SetAnswer()
    }
}

// in your UI code:
itemView.Question.SetAnswer(itemView.Answer);
```

Comment: +1; This is a good idea.  See the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).  I'd also add a `string username` parameter to this function, rather than trying to grab out `User.Identity.Name`, for the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

I have this `Apply` extension method I like to use, for applying LINQ lambda expressions to objects. You could use it to assign multiple properties a little more succinctly than in the original code:

```
itemView.Question.Apply(x => {
    x.AnswersJSON = itemView.Answer.ToJSONString();
    x.Modified = DateTime.Now;
    x.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name
});

public static class Helpers
{
    public static T Apply<T>(this T self, Action<T> lambda)
    {
        lambda(self);
        return self;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great to combine with EF, as I have an entity with lots of properties and was looking to just replace the item by its index, but that cannot be done with `IEnumerable<>` and when you do `ToList()` to be able to use indexes you lose your connection to EF. This is a much better solution than lots of `d.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == d.Id).val= d.val;`

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: Note that there is some discord around whether or not LINQ queries should intentionally create/rely on side-effects. Some people will surely frown upon using this helper method.

Answer (score 3):

If that Question is a class, then you could shorten the code a bit:

```
    var q = itemView.Question;
    q.AnswersJSON = itemView.Answer.ToJSONString();
    q.Modified = DateTime.Now;
    q.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Sure, you could. But this doesn't really simplify the code or make it any easier to read. `itemView` is not a particularly long variable name.

Comment: That's why I said "shorten the code" instead of "simplify" :-).

Comment: @Cody: Repeated access of `Question` is not a good idea though.  It could be a property, and referencing it the way the OP shows will repeatedly call its getter method.  This is most surely not what he wants to do.  Hans' example is nearly always what should be done instead.

Comment: @Merlyn: I disagree. Any C#/.NET coding style guidelines that you can get your hands on will tell you that all properties should be written so that they're virtually as cheap to call as using a field. The .NET team intended the distinction to be almost irrelevant to the average programmer; this was so important that properties and fields look very much the same syntactically. The JITer will inline any trivial `get` method, which makes the performance difference unmeasurable. I certainly don't follow this in *all* of my code as a matter of course.

Comment: @Cody: I concede your point for well written code.  A non-trivial getter should use method syntax.  But the OP isn't repeating `itemView`, but `itemView.Question`.  `itemView.Question` requires a (minuscule) level of indirection to think about, and sub-properties of `Question` require one more level.  Repeating it amplifies that indirection, and makes it less readable.  I would fully agree with you if someone were to replace `itemView.Prop1 = ...; itemView.Prop2 = ...;` with `var i = itemView; i.Prop1 = ...; i.Prop2 = ...`