# How to shorten access to multiple properties of the same object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is the type of code I often end up writing:

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.id = 'element';
element.style.position = 'absolute';
element.style.width = '100%';
element.style.height = '100%';
element.style.left = '0';
element.style.top = '0';
element.style.zIndex = '10000';
```

[Here's a very similar question in C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729701/how-can-i-simplify-c-sharp-code-that-sets-multiple-properties-of-an-object) How would you implement that in JavaScript?:

```
itemView.Question
    .AnswersJSON(itemView.Answer.ToJSONString())
    .Modified(DateTime.Now)
    .ModifiedBy(User.Identity.Name);
```

So it looks more like this:

```
element.id = 'element';
        .style.position = 'absolute';
        .style.width = '100%';
        .style.height = '100%';
        .style.left = '0';
        .style.top = '0';
        .style.zIndex = '10000';
```

Is this kind of solution the only possible one to make that code shorter?:

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
const e = element;
e.id = 'element';
e.style.position = 'absolute';
e.style.width = '100%';
e.style.height = '100%';
e.style.left = '0';
e.style.top = '0';
e.style.zIndex = '10000';
```

Comment: How about using a style sheet with classes instead of ids?

Comment: If you absolutely must inline styles though, you should be able to use `e.style.cssText = "ALL CSS HERE";`

Comment: if you really need to do these kinds of manipulations in Javascript, I would suggest using jQuery, which does allow method chaining, so you could do `$(e).width("100%").height("100%")...` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no chainable setter methods on DOM elements, and they wouldn't really be much shorter anyway. But don't repeat the `element.style` access every time! Just write

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.id = 'element';
const style = element.style;
style.position = 'absolute';
style.width = '100%';
style.height = '100%';
style.left = '0';
style.top = '0';
style.zIndex = '10000';
```

Alternatively use `Object.assign` if you don't want to spell out those many property assigments:

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.id = 'element';
Object.assign(element.style, {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    left: '0',
    top: '0',
    zIndex: '10000',
});
```

And last but not least, you can simply assign a CSS string to the [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) directly (but notice it's often considered a bad practice on already existing elements):

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.id = 'element';
element.style = 'position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0; zIndex:10000;';
```

or even

```
const element = Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {
    id: 'element',
    style: 'position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0; zIndex:10000;',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use object syntax and encapsulate your styles

```
const style1 = {
   position: 'absolute',
   width: '100%',
   height: '100%',
   left: '0',
   top:'0',
   zIndex: '10000'
}

element.id = 'element';
element.style = style1;
```

Then you can do things like use this object as base styles object and replace values using the es6 syntax ie.

```
newStyles = { 
   ...styles,
   width: '30%',
   height: '30%',
}
```

the Document API does not allow chaining in the way you suggest, if your goal is to reduce the amount of lines of code the above solution will allow this and make your code reusable and extendible;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document